# Reading characteristic on Android api 33

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My application runs on multiple APIs, not only API 33. I'm currently dealing with the `OnCharacteristicRead` event, i have both a deprecated and a new method. On API 33, I'm noticing that both the deprecated and the new `OnCharacteristicRead` methods are invoked. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found problem.

```
        public override void OnCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, byte[] value, GattStatus status)
        {
            //base.OnCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, value, status);

            readCharacteristics(value, status);
        }
```

base method should not be called!!! By some reason `base.OnCharacteristicRead` invoke deprecated method   `void OnCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, GattStatus status)` in api 33

Answer (score 0):

You had to share the code for your BluetoothGattCallback implementation. However, I can share the findings from my research during the time I was working on integrating Bluetooth into one of my projects.

If your device is running on Android 13+ and if your app has:

- compileSdkVersion 33+
- targetSdkVersion 33+

Then only new method will be called (which is not marked as deprecated):

```
public void onCharacteristicRead(@NonNull BluetoothGatt gatt, @NonNull BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, @NonNull byte[] value, int status)`
```

For devices running on Android 12 and earlier the old method (which became `@Deprecated` from 33 API) the old method will be called, which is:

```
@Deprecated
public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status)
```

Comment: tnx for your reply. It is in xamarin android, so I can't mark method with```deprecated```.  I add check of api version in my method, still. It is more theoretical question. to understand, how app will behave

Comment: Whatever framework you use, Android system calls the first method for API 33+, and the second method on previous versions of API. If there are some peculiarities in Xamarin, you can add manually check of API version and rely on logic that I described above

Answer (score 0):

From document [Deprecations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/deprecations), we could find that:

> With each release, specific Android APIs may become obsolete or need
> to be refactored to provide a better developer experience or support
> new platform capabilities. In these cases, Android will officially
> deprecate the obsolete APIs and direct developers to new APIs to use
> instead.
>
> Deprecation means that we’ve ended official support for the APIs, but
> they will continue to remain available to developers.

So, the Deprecated API is still available, but we don't recommend it. We generally recommend using the latest APIs. In addition, it is not necessary to use both the Deprecated API and the latest API at the same time, they serve the same purpose.

Comment: Tnx for reply. I know this. I my case i need both methods. I already found problem, why both was calling. i posted the answer